# call method from java fragment to kotlin fragment?

Tags: java, kotlin, fragment

can I call method from java fragment to kotlin fragment?

I want to call onclick method from java fragment to kotlin fragment, which when click, kotlin fragment works the same function as java fragment is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I got your question, but [Kotlin is 100% interoperable with Java](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/learn-kotlin-java-pathway).

So, if you are in a kotlin fragment and you have a reference to a java object that's the other fragment, you can call any public method on it just like you could with java:

```kotlin
javaFragment.onClick()
```